# Combobox in Asp.net issue

Tags: asp.net, combobox

I am using EntityFramework and i have an entity which is Customer.A customer could have other customers as References.P.k is CustomerID.
On the Page i have a FormView which contains Name,CustomerID,... and one Field which is reference is Combobox which is bound to CustomerReference Entity which has MasterCustomerID(CustomerID) and ReferenceCustomerID  .A customer could have Multiple references.
I want it displays the combobox with multiple selected Customers and also on the time of saving i will be able to save it CustomerReference entity.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dd" DataSourceID="ProjectForDropDownDataSource" DataTextField="...." DataValueField="..." SelectedValue='....%>'></asp:DropDownList>
```

Whats the Approach plz.
thx

Comment: I think the best approach would be to write code and come back if you have a specific problem...

Comment: Can u pls help me some code? thx

Comment: If you post it here, maybe some people will help you, that's the goal of SO. If you want someone to write code, I would suggest to hire and pay someone, or learn to do it yourself...